# R Removing earliest observations when duplicate IDs are present

Tags: r, time

I have a data frame which looks something like this:

```
ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4) 
TIME = as.POSIXct(c("2013-03-31 09:07:00", "2013-09-26 10:07:00", "2013-03-31 11:07:00",
                    "2013-09-26 12:07:00","2013-03-31 09:10:00","2013-03-31 11:11:00",
                    "2013-03-31 09:06:00","2013-09-26 09:04:00","2013-03-31 10:35:00",
                    "2013-09-26 09:07:00","2013-09-26 09:07:00","2013-09-26 10:07:00"))
var = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1) 
DF = data.frame(ID, TIME, var) 

   ID                TIME var
1   1 2013-03-31 09:07:00   0
2   1 2013-09-26 10:07:00   0
3   1 2013-03-31 11:07:00   1
4   1 2013-09-26 12:07:00   1
5   2 2013-03-31 09:10:00   0
6   2 2013-03-31 11:11:00   1
7   3 2013-03-31 09:06:00   0
8   3 2013-09-26 09:04:00   0
9   3 2013-03-31 10:35:00   1
10  3 2013-09-26 09:07:00   1
11  4 2013-09-26 09:07:00   0
12  4 2013-09-26 10:07:00   1
```

I would like to remove the row containing the earliest TIME value when there are identical ID and var present in the data, ie. to end up with something like this:

```
ID2 = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4) 
TIME2 = as.POSIXct(c("2013-09-26 10:07:00","2013-09-26 12:07:00","2013-03-31 09:10:00",
                     "2013-03-31 11:11:00","2013-09-26 09:04:00","2013-09-26 09:07:00",
                     "2013-09-26 09:07:00","2013-09-26 10:07:00"))
var2 = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1) 
DF2 = data.frame(ID2, TIME2, var2) 

  ID2               TIME2 var2
1   1 2013-09-26 10:07:00    0
2   1 2013-09-26 12:07:00    1
3   2 2013-03-31 09:10:00    0
4   2 2013-03-31 11:11:00    1
5   3 2013-09-26 09:04:00    0
6   3 2013-09-26 09:07:00    1
7   4 2013-09-26 09:07:00    0
8   4 2013-09-26 10:07:00    1
```

As you can see it is not simply about avoiding the measurements performed in March 2013, since these are valid. It is only the measurements for which there are "duplicates" and have been performed again in September that should be affected (see for example that ID = 2 remains in DF2).

Hope you can help.

Sincerily,
ykl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(ID, var) %>% filter(n() == 1L | !TIME %in% min(TIME))
#Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
#Groups: ID, var
#
#  ID                TIME var
#1  1 2013-09-26 10:07:00   0
#2  1 2013-09-26 12:07:00   1
#3  2 2013-03-31 09:10:00   0
#4  2 2013-03-31 11:11:00   1
#5  3 2013-09-26 09:04:00   0
#6  3 2013-09-26 09:07:00   1
#7  4 2013-09-26 09:07:00   0
#8  4 2013-09-26 10:07:00   1
```

What this does:

- Take the data frame DF
- group it by ID and var
- the filter function is used to filter out (subset) by row. it takes a logical vector
  and returns rows for which the vector is TRUE. The logic is:
  1) if the group has only 1 row, i.e. `n() == 1L`, then always return that row.
  2) if the group has more than 1 rows, i.e. `n() > 1L`, then check if the `TIME` value is
     equal to the minimum (earlist) TIME value of the group. By using `!` we negate the vector so that it is FALSE whenever TIME is at its minimum. Those 1) and 2) conditions are combined with an OR (`|`).

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. Can you quickly explain what the filter() function and its contents signify?

Comment: I added an explanation, @ykl

Comment: Nice, much appreciated.

Comment: Oh btw, what if you had 3 different values for a ID - var combination? would you want to remove the _two_ earliest, i.e. only keep the max or do you only want to remove the earliest?

Comment: I simplified the code a little bit - the `n() > 1L` is not necessary in this case.

Comment: The problem I am faced with only entails 2 different values for an identical ID - var combination. Nonetheless, I am indeed interested in learning what the code should be should I have 3 different values.

Comment: But you haven't answered my question what you would expect in such a case.. so I can't tell you what to do.

Comment: @ykl I would guess it should be the same.  You can provide an example as suggested by docendo discimus

Comment: If you wanted to only keep the (first) max TIME, you could for example do `DF %>% group_by(ID, var) %>% slice(which.max(TIME))` with dplyr or `aggregate(TIME ~ ID + var, DF, max)` with base R.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[ ,{if(.N==1) .SD else .SD[-which.min(TIME)]}, by=list(ID, var)]
#   ID var                TIME
#1:  1   0 2013-09-26 10:07:00
#2:  1   1 2013-09-26 12:07:00
#3:  2   0 2013-03-31 09:10:00
#4:  2   1 2013-03-31 11:11:00
#5:  3   0 2013-09-26 09:04:00
#6:  3   1 2013-09-26 09:07:00
#7:  4   0 2013-09-26 09:07:00
#8:  4   1 2013-09-26 10:07:00
```

Or a similar logical approach as showed by @docendo discimus

```
setDT(DF)[DF[,.N==1L|!TIME %in% min(TIME), by=list(ID, var)]$V1]
```